# dropdown list with preset closed height breaking dynamic height variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

why ello!

Im trying to get a list of boxes, all with variable height, to be able to hide / show the content with .animate() on one function. Im trying to get the height of the content boxes with .height() which works... however I also need to set the boxes height to start at 0px so the page loads and the boxes are closed to begin with.

The problem arises with me being bad with variables. I can get the thing to work, but as soon as i set all the boxes to start at 0px(globally)... the variable I set on Click to find the content size finds the size of 0px that I set for the initial state... so the boxes can close but have no height to reopen to.

If you comment out the first line in my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sf46e/1/) , like below , you can see it sort of working:

```
//$(".className").find("p").not(".trigger").css({height: '0px'});
```

*BTW: I know the way I made the selectors with $(this).parent().bla().bla().bla(); is not the most efficient way of selecting these items but my sites actual code is more complex and I wanted to keep it similar. THX!*

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
/** Set up an object. **/
var allElementHeightsOriginally = {
                                      heights: {}
                                  };
var triggerElementHeight = $(".trigger").height();
/** Add the original heights to the object, along with the element indices. **/
$(".className").each(function (index, element) {
    allElementHeightsOriginally.heights[index] = {
        index: index,
        original: ($(element).height()-triggerElementHeight)
    };
});
/** Your click event. **/
$(".trigger").click(function () {   
    var indexClicked = $(".trigger").index(this);
    var theElement = $(this).parent().find("p").not(".trigger");
    $.each(allElementHeightsOriginally.heights, function (theKey, valueArray){   
        if(indexClicked == theKey){
            var height = valueArray.original;
            $selected = $(theElement);
            if ($(theElement).hasClass('toggle')) {
                $selected.stop().animate({height:"0px"});
                $(theElement).removeClass('toggle');
            } else {
                $selected.stop().animate({height: height + 'px' });
                $(theElement).addClass('toggle');
            }
        }
    });
});
/** Collapse by default. **/
$("p").not(".trigger").css({height: '0px'});
```

I'm not sure whether the code above follows best practices, but it certainly does work!